# What is EulerSum method in NumericalCalculus's ND?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The NumericalCalculus package in Mathematica provide `ND` function that deals with numerical differentiation. The doc says, the default option for `Method` is 'EulerSum'. However, I can not find any 'differentia...' keywords on 'Euler summation' wikipedia page. I also got no clues after reading chapters on differentiation of several numerical analysis books(it seems that Euler summation is not mentioned). Could someone help elaborating on the technical detail of 'EulerSum' in differentiation? What on earth is this method?

Comment: You can inspect the code with first ``Needs@"NumericalCalculus`"`` and then ``GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions@NumericalCalculus`ND``

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you so much for showing me the way. I spent quite some time to read the code, it is purely wolfram language. Finally, I realize what it is doing is quite standard procedure that is explained in textbooks. Basically forward difference with a Richardson’s Extrapolation. However, I still can not relate it to Euler summation. Though according to wikipedia, Euler summation is related to binomial transform, and binomial transform is related to forward difference. But there is no mention of Euler summation in Richardson’s Extrapolation wiki page.

Comment: You're welcome.  BTW, I can't explain the connection to Euler summation either.